# Is *every* autonomous first-order planar/2D system integrable?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-equations, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, integrable-systems

Consider a general autonomous first-order planar/2D system:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = A(x,y)\\
\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = B(x,y),
\end{cases}$$

where $A,B$ are two functions. Reading [*Classical Mechanics* by Joseph L. McCauley](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/classical-mechanics/8EED8DB12A2674B04B627527CFF6A6B1) I found the following statements:

> Every two dimensional flow, $$dx/dt = A(x,y), \qquad dy/dt = B(x,y),$$ whether dissipative or conservative, has a conservation law,

and, if we rewrite the system equations as $dt=dx/A=dy/B$,

> every differential form $B(x,y)dx-A(x,y)dy=0$ in two variables either is closed or else has an integrating factor $M(x,y)$ that makes it integrable.

So is really *every* planar system integrable, or have I missed some detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A global [integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) statement for general [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) 2D systems does not hold, but a local integrability statement is true. Let us reformulate OP question as follows.

> *Suppose that we are given an autonomous two-dimensional first-order problem*
> $$ \dot{x}~=~f(x,y), \qquad   \dot{y}~=~g(x,y), \tag{1}$$
> *where $f$ and $g$ are two given smooth functions. Is eq. (1) a Hamiltonian system
> $$  \dot{x}~=~\{x,H\}, \qquad   \dot{y}~=~\{y,H\}, \tag{2}$$
> with a symplectic structure $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ and Hamiltonian $H(x,y)$?*

The answer is, perhaps surprisingly: *Yes, always, at least locally.
The Hamiltonian $H$ is the sought-for [integral of motion/first integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion#Integral_of_motion).*

1. *Proof:* In two dimensions, a [Poisson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) is completely specified by the fundamental Poisson bracket relations
   $$ \{x,y\} ~=~B(x,y)~=~-\{y,x\}, \qquad \{x,x\}~=~0~=~\{y,y\}, \tag{3} $$
   where $B$ is some function that doesn't take the value zero. [Exercise: Check that eqs. (3) automatically satisfy the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity).] The Hamilton's eqs. (2) become
   $$  \dot{x}~=~B\frac{\partial H}{\partial y}, \qquad   \dot{y}~=~-B\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}.\tag{4} $$
   Next consider the one-form
   $$ \eta ~:=~ f{\rm d}y -g{\rm d}x, \tag{5}$$
   which is possibly an [inexact differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential). However, it is known from the theory of PDE's, that there locally exists an integrating factor $\frac{1}{B}$, so that the one-form
   $$ \frac{1}{B}\eta~=~{\rm d}H \tag{6} $$
   is locally an [exact differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential) given by some function $H$. It is straightforward to check that one can use $B$ as the Poisson structure (3) and $H$ as the Hamiltonian. $\Box$
2. *Remark.* The existence of a pair of canonical variables $q(x,y)$ and $p(x,y)$, with $\{q,p\}=1$, are, in turn, guaranteed locally by [Darboux' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem).
3. *Example:* If $f$ and $g$ are [homogeneous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) of same order, and if one chooses
   $$ B~=~ y f - x g, \tag{7}$$
   then one may check that the one-form $\frac{1}{B}\eta$ is closed. A Hamiltonian $H$ can hence be found via contour integration of the one-form (6).
4. *Example: 1D [damped oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Damped_harmonic_oscillator):* Eqs. of motion:
   $$ \dot{v}~=~-2bv-\omega^2x, \qquad \dot{x}~=~v. \tag{8}$$
   Poisson bracket:
   $$ B(x,v) ~=~ v^2 + 2 b v x + \omega^2 x^2. \tag{9}$$
   Hamiltonian:
   $$\begin{align} H(x,v)~=~&\frac{1}{2}\ln|B(x,v)|\cr
   ~+~&\left\{\begin{array}{ccr} 
   \frac{b}{\sqrt{\omega^2-b^2}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{\omega^2-b^2} x}{v + b x}&\text{if underdamped}& |b|~<~ \omega,\cr\cr 
   \frac{bx}{v + b x}&\text{if critically damped}& |b|~=~ \omega,\cr\cr 
   \frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2-\omega^2}}\left\{\begin{array}{c}{\rm artanh}\cr{\rm arcoth}\end{array}\right\}\frac{\sqrt{b^2-\omega^2} x}{v + b x}&\text{if overdamped}& |b|~>~ \omega.\cr 
   \end{array}  \right.\tag{10} \end{align}$$
5. *Example:* [Math.SE q1577274](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1577274/11127).
6. *Counterexample.* Solutions to diff. eqs. exist in general only locally. Consider
   $$f(q,p)~=~\frac{q}{q^2+p^2}\quad\text{and}\quad g(q,p)~=~\frac{p}{q^2+p^2}\tag{11}$$
   in the domain $D=\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\},$ which is not contractible. It is relatively straightforward to check that
   $$\eta~=~f\mathrm{d}p-g\mathrm{d}q ~=~\frac{q\mathrm{d}p-p\mathrm{d}q}{q^2+p^2} \tag{12}$$
   is a closed $1$-form, and there doesn't exist a *globally* defined Hamiltonian $H$ on $D$ such that eqs. (2) are satisfied. The best one can do is to put $H$ equal to a single-valued branch of ${\rm arg}(q+ip)$, which is *not* globally defined.
7. *Counterexample: Contractible domain without global solution:* [Math.SE q2710698](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2710698/11127).

Comment: Marvelous answer! In *so much* textbooks I've looked into, the generic planar differential system is shown as an example of NONintegrable system!

Comment: Just to be sure @Qmechanic, the local integrability stands also in the case $A$ and $B$ in my example are nonlinear?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes. For a non-linear example see e.g. point 5.

Comment: Notes for later: 1. Separable case: $f(x,y)=a(x)b(y)$, $g(x,y)=c(x)d(y)$, $B(x,y)=a(x)d(y)$. 2. Affine ODE: $f(x,y)=c(x)Y^{\prime}(y)$, $g(x,y)=a(x)Y(y)+b(x)$, $B(x)=c(x)\exp\int^x \!dx^{\prime}~a(x^{\prime})/c(x^{\prime})$.