# Set of first order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

What's the condition for

$\dot{x} = f(x,y)\\
\dot{y} = g(x,y)$

To be rewritable as

$\dot{x} = \frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\\
\dot{y} = -\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}$

Can I always find a transformation $z=z(x,y)$ such that

$\dot{x} = \frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial z}\\
\dot{z} = -\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}$

Comment: It might be worth asking this on mathematics S.E. instead. Also, you should include your own attempts at the problem in the body of the question. We require working for most questions, to prevent users from answering a persons homework for them, without the person attempting it themselves first.

Comment: Possible  duplicate: [Is *every* planar/2D system integrable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432664/2451)