# Integrability of one-dimensional system of motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, complex-systems, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

How can I prove that every one-dimensional system is integrable (meaning that there is a constant of motion)?

It is clear that if $H$ does not depend explicitly on time then $H$ is indeed a constant of motion, (that is the energy).

If $H$ is time dependent I have tried various examples but found no common constant. Is there a known way to find such constants of motion? I am aware that those constants may be related to Hamilton-Jacobi equations or Louiville's Theorem. Could you please indicate how to find such a constant in general.

Comment: Hi SultanDeGranada Welcome to Phys.SE. Do you mean a _globally defined_ constant of motion? Who makes the claim for 1D systems with explicit time-dependence? Which page?

Comment: At a Lecture we were asked to prove it.

Comment: And the lecturer specifically mentioned explicit time-dependence?

Comment: If the system is "autonomous" (no explicit time dependence, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics) ), see this answer and links therein: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/583869/226902 .  More useful terminology here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/226902

Comment: He did not made explicit mention of time dependece but otherwise it is trivial.